# Automatic push to a Docker private registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I've set up a Docker private registry and I need to push images to this one from a script that is triggered on each successfull build (build is done with Drone from a dedicated build container).

When I issue a 'docker push', I first need to authentify to be able to push to the registry.

Is there any setup I could use to keep the credential somewhere and use it within the script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that .dockercfg was used to keep the credential and the address of the registry.
Setting this .dockercfg in the $HOME dir fixed the thing.

Answer (score 1):

The way I envisioned it was to just run the command in my scripts to authenticate to docker before you push the image:

```
docker login –u <your_username> –p <your_password> <your_docker_registry_fqdn>
```

I think it is easier to maintain the script should you have a change in the username or password or have multiple users, no need to download another credentials file which you will have to manually generate with the new password or username.